# SQL if exist update quantity

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

What I'm trying to achieve is a single form where user with a handheld barcode reader read the barcode and the page on each read send a SQL command to record the number of product scanned.

I have a database named packinglist and a table named list with two columns barcode and quantity.

I have this string on the page:

```
INSERT INTO `gpbeticlm`.`packinglist` (barcode,quantity) VALUES (':field',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=VALUES(quantity);
```

The first time I read a barcode it is inserted correctly in the database with quantity 1, but the second time I read the same barcode instead of having quantity 2 it doesn't update the database and remain 1, so I try to read another barcode and it doesn't do nothing the database keep 1 row with quantity 1.

Comment: We need table structure... `SHOW CREATE TABLE gpbeticlm.packinglist` aswell to debug whats "wrong"

Answer (score 0):

If the barcode is the primary key of the table, you could use the `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construct

You can find more information about this construct [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/)

I'll try to clarify a bit.

You're doing `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=VALUES(quantity);`, which takes the inserted value (which is `1`) as the value to write in the updated field. So this will always be `1` instead of the incremented value.

You could rewrite this construct as mentioned in the beforementioned link to something like this

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=quantity + 1`